# node-gyp: Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

Tags: java, node.js, node-modules, node-gyp

i got a strange Issue which seems to be unique in the internet. It all started with a simple

```
sudo npm install java
```

This resulted in :

```
4 warnings generated.
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node
ld: library not found for -ljli
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/bob/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/bob/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node" "/Users/bob/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/bob/Documents/node-synfis-backend/node_modules/java
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN synfis-backend@0.9.1 No description
npm WARN synfis-backend@0.9.1 No repository field.
npm WARN The package @types/fs-extra is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! java@0.12.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.12.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bob/.npm/_logs/2020-02-21T08_10_18_068Z-debug.log
```

I did a lot of research on the internet and grabbed every straw i found. In the end nothing works and i hope this is not the obvious error in the universe.

I appreciate every help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: i use sudo, because i got some access issues while the installation. I need the java bridge to use the openoffice java classes to fill out some odt files. (i did not find any JS Class that could do the trick). Yes i have python 2.7 installed, because i found this hin ton the internet.

Comment: Then it's time to, rather than on Stackoverflow, literally ask the people who make this: search https://github.com/joeferner/node-java/issues and if there's no answer there, post an issue so that they can fix what might very well be a bug. And remember: SO is basically your last resort, when dealing with open source, the official docs and issue trackers should always come first =)

Comment: https://github.com/joeferner/node-java/issues/494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved/avoided by downgrading to

java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you are using Node 13. See [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/gyp-err-stack-error-make-failed-with-exit-code-2/24040/12).

The error occurs when building Couchbase using make.

If you use nvm or similar, switch to Node 12 and try again.

Also, what the heck are you doing installing Java - with Node! :-P

Comment: so i installed nvm and now running on node.js 12 lts. but i get a familiar error message:

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

*node-gyp* is used to compile native modules, but in this case it is not necessary. In my case, it tried to compile node-sass and then the same error as yours ocurred.

Everytime that I ran npm install and a hidden folder ".node-gyp" was created in my home directory, i knew there was a problem

I was using node 12.18.3. I started to try some older versions.

My OS was a Linux Mint 19.1. When i chose its node system version, the **8.10.0**, the problem has been solved.